# Custom Post Templates

Tags: posts, filters, templates, single

**The Issue:** I am looking for *custom* single post templates, to add or remove individual elements as a function of a normal single post.

There are a lot of ways to create custom post templates for single posts within WordPress. Especially post formats are a great chance to use *default* templates for default cases; however I need real *custom* templates for every post.

**The Idea:** My first approach was to add an if/else statement according to the post ID:

```
// check if custom post
if ( is_single('999') )
    // check if there is a custom post template file
    if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-999.php' )
        // use custom post template
        return TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-999.php'; 
// use normal post template for everything else
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single.php');
```

Well, this isn't wrong, but it would totally mess up my template code if there will be more and more special cases.
So maybe I can use a filter to always use a custom template if there is one that corresponds with the post ID:

```
add_filter( 'single_template', function( $template ) {
    // check if there is a custom post template file
    if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-' . $GLOBALS['post']->ID . '.php') )
        // use custom post template
        return TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-' . $GLOBALS['post']->ID . '.php';
    // use normal post template for everything else
    return $template;
});
```

But now I will end up with a lot of custom template files, that are all the same except some minor changes.

**More Thoughts:** I think I would rather like to add dynamic sections within the `single.php` template, to hook in with custom includes/filters?

**The Question:** Is there a different (more exclusive) approach to get those kind of *custom* post templates?

**Update:** In a lot of these special cases I need to add some additional StyleSheets or JavaScripts, but also custom container with HTML and also PHP content (this is why I tried to do it with custom templates instead of custom fields). Most of the time the additional elements are above, below or beside `the_content()`.

Comment: can you explain more what you mean by "except some minor changes"? how are these custom single post templates different?

Comment: @birgire Check the **Update** within my question :)

Comment: some themes use metaboxes in the post edit page for this kind of customization, so you don't have to edit the logic inside functions.php or add a new single-123.php file each time you add a new post.

Comment: @birgire Is it a good idea to insert PHP content this way? I don't have to update `functions.php`; but I need to create one more `single-{id}.php` file...

Comment: some themes allow PHP in metaboxes, I don't like it. You could try to use shortcodes or use forms with options/selects/inputs.

Comment: look up the template heirarchy, it already accounts for specific templates for specific page and post IDs

Comment: hmmm no thats only for pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is finally possible with WordPress 4.4 (as announced on [Make WordPress Core](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/10/07/single-post_type-post_name-php-new-theme-template-in-wordpress-4-4/)).

The WordPress [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) now allows *single custom post templates* with a naming pattern like this:

```
single-{post_type}-{post_name}.php
```

Quoting from John Blackbourn the templates follows these rules:

> This template follows the rules of [`is_single()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) and is used for
>   a single post or custom post type. [...] It comes in the hierarchy
>   before `single.php` and `single-{post_type}.php`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this approach will work.

1.create template for single post like `singlepost.php`( default single post template),`singlepost-99.php`,`singlepost-101.php`.

2.now put just this code in `single.php`

```
<?php
global $post;
get_template_part('singlepost',$post->ID);
?>
```

what this code does check for single post template for current post by post id if not found call `singlepost.php`.

**Important Link**:

[get_template_part()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)

Comment: by using this you don't have to update your `functions.php`.read this [post](http://kovshenin.com/2013/get_template_part/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it a template, you have to add a comment:

```
<?php
  /*
  Template Name: Page, two columns
  */
  get_header();
?>
```

Whatever name you assign in the comment -

can be selected as template within WP-admin sidebar.

Like this you won't end up with hundreds of different template-bits.

I mean, even if the above solution works - one has to consider maintenance.

Comment: Good point, but I think that's only for pages,...

Comment: Indeed, requires a plugin to support it:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-template/

Comment: you could switch by post-type (instead of IDs):
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates

Comment: b/c the above solution requires the user to manually maintain files and ID - instead of simply using an already prepared template (which can get problematic, because every revision and auto-saved edit will get a new ID assigned).